# Monotouch and xcode 3 and xcode 4

Tags: xcode, xamarin.ios, xcode4, monodevelop

Im installed a monotouch (monodevelop), xcode 3 and xcode 4...

Im make a separated location for xcode 3 and xcode 4 so i can run side by side.

So the problem is...

When i launch monotouch and click on .xib file..the software detect as xcode 4 to launch an interface not xcode 3.

So, is there any setting should i change to make xcode 3 as default interface for monodevelop ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you need to set the default application;

- Find any .xib on your HDD in Finder and Right Click -> Get Info it.
- In the "Open With" section, change the drop down to "Interface Builder" and click "Change All..."

this is taken from [Geoff Norton's blog](http://blog.sublimeintervention.com/archive/2011/Apr-25.html).